# google slides html integration: start on specific slide

Tags: html, iframe, google-docs, google-slides

I'm using an html integration on Wix to include a google slide presentation in a specific webpage. I've got lots of different web pages that I'd like to use a specific slides from in the presentation, so to save time I thought I could do this through the HTML integration (also helps with editing).

How can I start the presentation on a specific slide?

Bonus points, is there anyway to get rid of the frame on the outside that says the source is google docs?

Answer (score 3):

Each slide has a unique ID, So for each slide you wish to start it on you can

1) open the slide and go to the slide you want it to start on
2) in the URL the last param is something like "&slide=id.XXXXX"
3) In the iFrame add this "&slide=id.XXXXX" to the end of the URL string

It will now load to the first slide. Repeat for other web pages.

Comment: As of 2023, this doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
&rm=minimal
```

to the end of the URL and it will remove the controls